# Настройка сервера Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, apache, сервер

Купил VDS на WINDOWS SERVER 2003.

Задачи такие:

1. Надо поставить Apache, Php, MySQL, PhpMyAdmin.
2. Можно ли это сделать без IIS?
3. Правильно ли я решил ставить windows server или надо было Linux юзать?
4. Как Apache выпустить в интернет.

Comment: 1) Удачи. 2) Да. 3) 50/50, если знаешь обе ОС, иначе - правильно. 4) Разрешить внешние подключения. Нужен "белый" адрес или маппинг с такового на интерфейсе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чисто технически, ничего не запрещает вам поставить на ОС Windows такие вещи как apache, php, MySql и тем более PhpMyAdmin: вполне есть дистрибутивы для всего этого и под винду в том числе.

Просто как-то принято ставить LAMP на машины с linux-операционками. Ну и поэтому ответ на третий вопрос в общем-то зависит от вас: хотите - ставьте, хотите возьмите VDS c каким-нибудь linux.

Наиболее популярный сейчас вариант это Debian (доля рынка 60-70%), либо CentOS (практически весь - в корпоративном сегменте).

Если хочется всё же на базе ОС Windows - ставьте, всё поставится без проблем. (Это ответ на ваш первый вопрос). Скачали дистрибутивы и через Next - Next - Next - ... - Finish поставится практически всё.

Можно ли это сделать без установки IIS? Да, можно. IIS - это аналог apache, веб-сервер. Можете поставить Apache и сверху ставить PHP и всё остальное, а можете поставить вместо Apache IIS (Ну, через добавление роли) и потом опять всё остальное ставить поверх. Это ответ на второй вопрос.

Как выпустить apache в интернет.

Есть два базовых варианта: у вас сервер стоит у провайдера VDS и он выдал на машину белый IP-адрес (самый типичный случай), вам ничего не придётся вообще делать. Максимум - проверить, что firewall не закрывает апач.

Второй вариант мог бы быть, если бы сервер стоял у вас дома - тогда надо было бы на вашем роутере, который доставляет интернет в квартиру настраивать NAT, либо проброс порта, потом возиться не дай бог с настройкой DynDNS (если айпишник не фиксирован).

Что ещё, из того, что вы не спросили. ОС Windows 2003 давно снята с технической поддержки вендором, сейчас принято ставить на базе Windows Server 2012 R2. Вы же не хотите быть взломанным, верно?

Comment: LAMP - Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP. Такая терминология априори предполагает Линукс. В данном контексте правильней будет написать  AMP :D Простите за придирчивость.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside Спасибо за комментарий! Действительно, вы правы - и кстати, это вовсе не придирчивость, а точность формулировок.